# React Native packager not locating package.json

Tags: json, react-native, npm, atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I installed Atom and Nuclide and opened a newly initialized React Native Project in Atom. Once I try to start the React Native Packager I am getting an error stating

> An unexpected error occurred while running the React Native Packager process:
>   ENOTDIR: not a directory, stat '/Users/UserName/Documents/MyProjectDirectory/ProjectName/package.json/package.json'

[image]

There is no directory called package.json and I'm not aware how this path could have become corrupted. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Encountering the same issue. Not sure what we're missing.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but a workaround for now:

> You can run the following to start the packager manually: `npm start`

Or, generally, running `react-native run-ios` (or `run-android`) will start the packager as a matter of course (in a separate terminal window).

(Also no clue why this is happening; for me, it was after the upgrade from RN `0.49` ~> `0.50`.)